# Psexec or WMI with parameters

Tags: c#, wmi, psexec

I need to run a Powershell script in a remote computer.

This script prompts the user for variable values, but if I execute the script remotely with PsExec or WMI, I don't see any prompt.

Is there a way to pass parameters to the Powershell script through WMI or PsExec?

Comment: I know in command prompt there is the ["pipe trick"](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termsr/a/redirection-operator.htm), but I don't know if that translates to Power Shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594587/passing-parameters-to-powershell-from-c-sharp